# Query Takes more time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 with 553,386 rows and every day it is increasing by about 400 rows. Now when I full scan of the table (`Select * from`) it is taking 23 sec. Is there any solution to speed up the query?

My PC configuration is, CPU: Intel Core 2 Duo 2.0 GHz, RAM: 4GB, OS: Windows 7 32 bit

Thanks in advance!

Table structure is given below:

```
USE [dbCPFL_Test]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PriceData]    Script Date: 10/04/2013 19:56:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PriceData](
    [TradeDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [Ticker] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ClsPRC] [float] NOT NULL,
    [No_of_Share] [float] NOT NULL,
    [TradeStatus] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Adj_MKTCap] [float] NOT NULL,
    [deList] [char](1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PriceData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [TradeDate] ASC,
    [Ticker] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Comment: Do you have a filter on the query? If just `Select * FROM PriceData` you cant speed that up.

Comment: Doing a `SELECT *` and asking for **all columns** and **all rows** will pretty much always result in a full table scan (or clustered index scan). Not much you can do to speed that up .... what you *could* do is (a) select less columns (use `SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM ....`) and/or (b) select less rows (use a `WHERE .....` clause). Then you *might* be able to get a speed boost with an index.

Comment: Creating a view of the table. and then query the view rather than directly querying the table. Not sure though :p

Answer (score 1):

Sure; upgrade your hardware.  Note that rendering results in Management Studio is notoriously slow, so keep that in mind if that is your performance benchmark tool.  However ...

The big question I have is: why do you care?  I'm hard pressed to come up with a legitimate reason to return the entire 550k record set.  You're not going to display that much on any screen in an application.  No one would ever view it.  If you're returning it for post-processing an aggregation or something of the sort, you should be aggregating it in SQL, then returning it.  If you are dumping it in an ETL process, long queries basically come with the territory (unless you're clever and come up with an incremental Extraction).

Answer (score 0):

> when I full scan of the table ....  Is there any solution to speed up [that]

Not that I'm aware of. A full table scan is a full table scan (hopefully it's actually a clustered index scan).

Adjusting a query back from all columns e.g. just the members of the clustered index might make a marginal difference, but there aren't a massive number of columns in that table.

Are you actually seeing 'full table scan' in execution plans? 
( if you do this "select * from [dbo].[PriceData] )